# Htaccess rewriting issues

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite

I seem to be having a lot of issues with my htaccess files

So, in my publuc_html, I have a CMS, with has rewrites enabled, by this:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z\-/]+)$ index.php?do=$1 [QSA]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
```

and in the public_html folder, I have a folder called forums, which is used by subdomain, forums.domain.com. The forum operated on vBSEO and this is the htaccess contents:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(admincp/|modcp/|cron|vbseo_sitemap)
RewriteRule ^((forums|archive/)?(.*\.php(/.*)?))$ vbseo.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/(admincp|modcp|clientscript|cpstyles|images|forums)/
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ vbseo.php [L,QSA]
```

How do I work this issue out? When I visit the subdomain, I am directed to [http://www.domain.com/forums](http://forums.domain.com/forums)?

Answer (score 1):

It might help to set up a [RewriteLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) directive so you can trace exactly what rewrites are happening and figure out where the problem lies.

Also, I might be able to give a better answer if you could clarify (A) what rewriting you're aiming for, and (B) what you're actually getting.

Is that correct?